# how to recover gem 1.5.0 to gem 1.4.0

Tags: ruby, rubygems

my rails can't work in gem 1.5.0 and how to recover it to the old version
any helps would be thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just specify the version in your Gemfile and do a 'bundle install'

```
gem 'gemname', '1.4.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are not using Bundler uninstall the newer gem and then install the old with the --version = flag

```
gem uninstall yourgem
gem install yourgem --verion=1.4.0
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to downgrade your gem from 1.5.0 to 1.4.0 all you need to do is:

```
gem update --system 1.4.0
```